# ParseObject with pointer to another ParseUser fails due to "ParseUser that is not authenticated"

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have project where I send messages between 2 and 2 ParseUsers, and save the messages as a ParseObjects where I keep a Pointer to the 2 users sending messages to each other. The code works for every user in the database except when I send a message to 1 particular user. Then I get "Cannot save a ParseUser that is not authenticated", so it seems like Parse tries to save the other User object, together with saving my message ParseObject, just with this one particular user.
Tried to create a "Save without data" object, but get the same error. Anyone experienced this before?

```
ParseObject message = new ParseObject("MSG");
message.put("sender", meUser);
message.put("receiver", otherUser);
message.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if( e== null){
                                Log.i(TAG, " Worked...");
                            }else {
                                e.printStackTrace();                                
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: can you try to user `otherUser.getObjectId()`? My guess is that you cannot save an non logged user using this.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried with just objectId, and then it works cause then Parse does not try to save the other ParseUser. But I dont understand why its saving the other ParseUser in the first place, cause Im only putting the pointer into another object, im not editing the other ParseUser in any way. In addition, Its just with one particular user it does not work, code works with messages between me and like 10 other users.

Comment: can you check the ACL of parse ?

Comment: The ParseUser class ACL right? Yeah, I check it and every user have just read access. And I guess that is why it does not work. But I dont want to have write access for other than the logged in user,I just dont understand why parse wants to save the other Pointer in the first place.

Comment: you should ask Parse.com, but I think I've already experienced this

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I actually did try to to change another users object. I found out where by backtracking using the "isDirty()" method on the object that was giving me issues to find out where I was making changes on the object. This method lead me to the root of the problem.
isDirty() returns true if you have made any changes to an object but not saved it yet.